# How can I differentiate between branches to use different environment variables in React Native Expo EAS?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to differentiate between branches in order to point my application to different backends and use different environment variables depending on the branch configured in EAS Update.

All the solutions I have found so far only refer to how to have different environment variables once you have built the app, so it doesn't work for me. Also I'm trying to avoid hardcoded environment configuration.

I am trying to make it possible to use it in the different branches that are uploaded to EAS and tested from the ExpoGO app.

Before SDK 46 and the current update and build cloud workflow I had workaround for this issue, but it's nor working anymore.

Comment: How are you managing your environment variables right now (before building the app with EAS)?